# Require syntax in node

Tags: node.js, requirejs

Is:

```
// Load the net module to create a tcp server.
var net = require('net');
```

using [require.js](https://requirejs.org/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't.

The function, `require`, is a function that node.js wrote by themselves.

Comment: This screencast might shed some light on the use of require with commonJS http://goo.gl/I3JLtB

Answer (score 5):

[`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require) is a globally-scoped function in Node.

Comment: The link above quotes: _"This variable may appear to be global but is not. See [require()](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require)."_